# Launch Linux Script remotely from Windows

Tags: linux, windows-7, scripting, remote-access, cross-platform

I have an `rsync` script that runs on one Linux server to synchronize files with another Linux server. Is there a way to launch a script on one of the Linux machines without actually opening an interactive `ssh` session to the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do it via a SSH command.   You just need to setup [plink.exe](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) .  You can download it at:
 http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Then, from a batch file like this one, exectute it:

```
@ECHO off
:: run remote command
plink.exe username@myserver /cygwin/C/Users/username/do-backup.sh
ECHO Remote command finished...
PAUSE>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shell script, then consider [Cywgin](http://www.cygwin.com). It takes a while to install, but you get a full suite of common Linux tools running on Windows, so you won't have to change your script at all.

Comment: but I'm looking to make a batch file or something like that, that will login into my linux bux and run that script... so it is possible by using Cywgin?

Comment: Yes. Bash in Cygwin is nearly the same as bash under any *nix.

Comment: Cygwin is quite complete, so you will also have all the other scripting languages available, Python, Ruby, Perl, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate a task, you might consider plink. It actually uses ssh (or telnet or raw) to connect to another machine. But you can use it to connect and run a command in one line. Check putty documentation for more details:

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/docs.html

Comment: actually I'm  not looking to automate this command. I'm looking to make it manual but then it should automatically login to server and run script. Actually I need rsync on different times so i want to keep it under my control to get rsycn whenever i want without going to server.

Comment: Then you just need to put it the line in a batch script as djangofan wrote and run the script when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have a pre-written script, but maybe you can get everything you need done with one of the many "rsync for cygwin repackages" like [cwrsync](https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync) and setting up a Windows scheduling job using cwrsync.